# Launch the Application class on app launch

Tags: android, android-manifest

I want my `Application` subclass choose if it need to launch the `Splashscreen` Activity or the `Main` Activity directly.

Is there a way that my `Application` subclass run without

```
  action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" 
  category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
```

on any activity element in the `Androidmanifest`?

Answer (score 0):

Always launch the Splashscreen activity, but in the onCreate, write the logic that decides whether to show the splash screen or the MainActivity. If you're showing MainActivity, call

```
onCreate(...)
    ...
    if (wantToShowSplash()) {
        // ... code to show splash stuff here ...
    } else {
        startIntent(MainActivity.class);
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: In fact the splashscreen was an example, my Application subclass had a lot of different things to do.Your answer is very good but have you an other suggest?

Comment: The two lines you posted just tell the android launcher that this activity should be in the list of activities the user can launch from the "application launcher". I believe you can register multiple activities to be launchable from the launcher. Alternatively, if you want to directly launch an activity of yours, you're able to do so via an Intent, just target it at that specific activity. If you could provide some scenarios I could probably help...